# Delta Live Tables consuming different files from the same path are combining the schema

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, delta-live-tables

### Summary

I am using Delta Live Tables to create a pipeline in Databricks and I am facing a problem of merging the schema of different files that are placed in the same folder in a datalake, even though I am using File Patterns to separate the data ingestion.

### Details

I have two files in the same path of a storage account. Consider `file_1` and `file_2`. They are placed in the Abfss location like:

`abfss://<container>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/folder/`

The `file_1` has a schema like:

- column_a
- column_b
- column_c

The `file_2` has a schema like:

- column_d
- column_e
- column_f

The code that I am applying to create the Delta Live Tables is the following one:

```
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE table_number_1 (
  CONSTRAINT correct_schema EXPECT (_rescued_data IS NULL)
)
PARTITIONED BY (_JOB_UPDATED_PARTITION_YEAR, _JOB_UPDATED_PARTITION_MONTH)
COMMENT "Comment for table 1"
TBLPROPERTIES (
  -- Quality flag
  'mypipeline.quality' = 'bronze',

  -- Delta Live Tables table properties
  'pipelines.autoOptimize.managed' = 'true',
  'pipelines.reset.allowed' = 'true',
  'pipelines.autoOptimize.zOrderCols' = '_JOB_UPDATED_PARTITION_YEAR, _JOB_UPDATED_PARTITION_MONTH',

  -- delta table options 
  'delta.enableDeletionVectors' = 'true',
  'delta.deletedFileRetentionDuration' = '30 days',
  'delta.enableChangeDataFeed' = 'true',
  'delta.feature.timestampNtz' = 'supported',

  -- enables special characters in the table 
  'delta.columnMapping.mode' = 'name',
  'delta.minReaderVersion' = '2',
  'delta.minWriterVersion'= '5'
)
AS 
SELECT 
  *,
  _metadata.file_path as _JOB_SOURCE_FILE,
  _metadata.file_name as _FILE_NAME,
  CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/Belem', _metadata.file_modification_time) as _MODIFICATION_TIME_BR,
  CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/Belem', current_timestamp()) as _JOB_UPDATED_TIME_BR,
  year(_JOB_UPDATED_TIME_BR) AS _JOB_UPDATED_PARTITION_YEAR,
  month(_JOB_UPDATED_TIME_BR) AS _JOB_UPDATED_PARTITION_MONTH,
  'Datalake' AS _DATA_ORIGIN
FROM cloud_files(
  "abfss://<container>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/folder/", 
  'csv',
  map(
    -- Generic options
    'fileNamePattern', '*file_1*',

    -- Common Auto Loader options
    'cloudFiles.allowOverwrites', 'true',
    'cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes', 'true',
    'cloudFiles.maxFilesPerTrigger', '1',

    -- CSV file format options
    'ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace', 'true',
    'ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace', 'true',
    'encoding', 'UTF-8',
    'header', 'true',
    'mode', 'FAILFAST',
    'multiLine', 'false',
    'readerCaseSensitive', 'false',
    'delimiter', ',',
    'skipRows', '0',

    -- Escape config
    'quote', '\"',
    'escape', '\"',
    'unescapedQuoteHandling', 'BACK_TO_DELIMITER'
  )
);
```

In this code I am referring the ABFSS path using the function `cloud_files()` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta-live-tables/sql-ref#--auto-loader-sql-syntax) but as the folder has different files then I am applying a `fileNamePattern` like the example `'*file_1*'`. According to the **Auto Loader** documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/auto-loader/options#generic-options) this is a generic option to provide a pattern for choosing files in a folder.

The problem is that when I start the DLT Pipeline to create the two tables, both of them are materialized with the following schema:

- column_a
- column_b
- column_c
- column_d
- column_e
- column_f

That is, somehow the DLT (Delta Live Table) when inferring the schema is combining all the files in the folder instead of using the `fileNamePattern` provided by me inside the `cloud_files` function.

That is strange because if I use `Auto Loader` instead of `DLT` via `read_files()` [link](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/read_files.html#read_files-table-valued-function) function then the tables are created in the expected way.

### The main question

Does someone know how to deal with this merging schema problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

Never use `'fileNamePattern', '*file_1*',`

Instead, put the pattern directly into the path:

`"abfss://<container>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/folder/*file_1*"`